# How I can use a relative path to access a building block in my macro?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to use a building block of a table that will be stored in a .dotm that is the user's STARTUP folder. However, I only know how to write the macro using an absolute file path but this won't work because the .dotm will be shared.

The .dotm file will also store the building block titled "sample table" and has everything formatted. I know I can rebuild the table using VBA but the widths never work out the way I need so I am trying using building blocks.

```
Application.Templates( _
    "C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP\Templates.dotm" _
    ).BuildingBlockEnries("sample_table").Insert Where:=Selection. _
    Range, RichTest:=True
```

Comment: What's the relative path? Is it going to be in the same folder or network share?

Comment: You could be looking for the `Environ()` function.  Type `?Environ("USERPROFILE")` or `?Environ("APPDATA")` in the immediate window for a quick example.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to get the path to Word's STARTUP folder in the user's home directory (the path is relative to each unique user).

The easiest way for your purpose is probably:

```
Application.Templates(Application.Options.DefaultFilePath(wdStartupPath) & "\" & _
    "Templates.dotm").BuildingBlockEntries("Sample_Table").Insert _
    Where:=Selection.Range, RichText:=True
```

However, there might be times when you want to scan through all global add-ins and base your decisions on what is found. Below is sample code for how that is done:

```
Sub FindAddin()
    Dim WordAddin As Word.AddIn
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Application.AddIns.Count
        If Application.AddIns(i).Name = "Templates.dotm" Then
            Set WordAddin = Application.AddIns(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If WordAddin Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.Templates(WordAddin.path & "\" & _
        WordAddin.Name).BuildingBlockEntries("Sample_Table").Insert _
        Where:=Selection.Range, RichText:=True
End Sub
```